# Query not displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display all page Names on a menu. But the pageName are not appearing however the hover effect is there. For example if there is 4 page name that need to be displayed - 4 hover effect, 2 pageName - 2 hover effect. That means it is looping through my database properly. But y it is not displaying?

[image]

```
<?php

            $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('could not connect to db:'. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die('No db found');
            $sql="SELECT * FROM page ";
            $query=mysql_query($sql)or die('Query failed');
            while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "
                <a href='".$result ['pageName']."'></a> ";

            }

            ?>
```

my table page

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page` (
  `pageID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `chapterID` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pageName` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `pageIcon` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `page_src` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tooltip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('Novice','Intermediate','Expert','') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `page`
--

INSERT INTO `page` (`pageID`, `chapterID`, `pageName`, `pageIcon`, `page_src`, `tooltip`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Networking Terms Explained', 'glyphicon glyphicon-file', 'networking_terms.html', 'Get Familiar with the terms', 'Novice');
```

Comment: **STOP** Using the depricated `myslq_* API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put something between `<a>Text here</a>` to display a text in your link.

You can change your :

```
echo "<a href='".$result ['pageName']."'></a> ";
```

Into :

```
echo "<a href='".$result ['page_src']."'>".$result ['pageName']."</a> ";
```

> In addition you should not use mysql_ functions, it's now deprecated
>   by PHP. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a href='".$result ['pageName']."'></a>` is empty.

Change from

```
<a href='".$result ['pageName']."'></a>
```

Into

```
<a href='".$result ['pageName']."'>Some Value</a>
```

> **Warning**: MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<a href='".$result ['pageName']."'>$result['pageName']</a> ";
```

Comment: Can you expand/explain this a bit? Popped up in review queue.